# Google drive sheets importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a way to import the data from one google drive sheet to another using ImportRange formula. However, I want the data to be synced once per day at a certain time instead of automatically updating as the formulas seems to do. Any help would really be appreciated

Formula used:

```
={IMPORTRANGE(B2,"sheet1!$A$1");IMPORTRANGE(B3,"sheet1!$A$1");IMPORTRANGE(B4,"sheet1!$A$1"); IMPORTRANGE(B5,"sheet1!$A$1");
  IMPORTRANGE(B6,"sheet1!$A$1")
}
```

Comment: You would need to use Apps Script if you want it to only happen at certain times of the day. Formulae will always stay updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Script (Google Apps Script) that copies the data automatically with **Time-driven Triggers** (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

```
function copyData() {
  // Gets data
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID1").getSheetByName("SheetName").getRange("A1:B2").getValues();

  // Copies data
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID2").getSheetByName("SheetName").getRange("A1:B2").setValues(data);
}
```